# Where do I add this function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a macro in my Excel Workbook that I run reports on.
I want to add in the pastespecial Function below but don't know where to place it in the script further down. It keeps giving me errors. I've tried almost every line.
I also want to add an extract phrase function added in as well. There is some text I want removed from one column at the beginning of every cell eg: alpha/beta/kappa
Help please.  Thank you.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Copy and Value Paste to Different Sheet
This example will Copy & Paste Values for single cells on different worksheets
1
2

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My code below where I want to insert the above pastespecial function:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Option Explicit

Function GetHeadersDict() As Scripting.Dictionary
' We must activate the Microsoft Scripting Runtime from Tools --References

Dim result As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set result = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With result
     
        .Add "Track #", False
        .Add "Date", False
        .Add "Status", False
        .Add "Shoes", False
        .Add "Description", False
       
        
    End With

    Set GetHeadersDict = result
    
End Function

Function FindHeaderRange(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal header As String) As Range

    Set FindHeaderRange = ws.Cells.Find(header, , , xlWhole)
    
End Function

Sub clearDataNotFormulasSheet2()

Sheets("Results").Range("A2:k96").ClearContents

End Sub


Sub copyColumnData()


On Error GoTo ErrorMessage
    
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
    
    clearDataSheet2

Dim numRowsToCopy As Long

    numRowsToCopy = ws1.Cells(RowIndex:=Rows.Count, ColumnIndex:=1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    'MsgBox "The no of rows to copy is " & numRowsToCopy
    
Dim destRowOffset As Long

    destRowOffset = ws2.Cells(RowIndex:=Rows.Count, ColumnIndex:=1).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox "The next Blank row is " & destRowOffset

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    
Dim dictKey As Variant
Dim header As String
Dim numColumnsToCopy As Long
Dim Report As Range
Dim dest As Range

Dim headersDict As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set headersDict = GetHeadersDict()

    For Each dictKey In headersDict
        header = dictKey
        If headersDict.Item(header) = False Then
            Set Report = FindHeaderRange(ws1, header)
            If Not (Report Is Nothing) Then
                Set dest = FindHeaderRange(ws2, header)
                If Not (dest Is Nothing) Then
                    headersDict.Item(header) = True
                    ' Look at successive headers to see if they match
                    ' If so, copy these columns altogether to make the macro faster
                    For numColumnsToCopy = 1 To headersDict.Count
                        'MsgBox numColumnsToCopy
                        If Report.Offset(ColumnOffset:=numColumnsToCopy).Value = dest.Offset(ColumnOffset:=numColumnsToCopy).Value Then
                            headersDict.Item(Report.Offset(ColumnOffset:=numColumnsToCopy).Value) = True
                            
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        
                    Next numColumnsToCopy

                    Report.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=numRowsToCopy, ColumnSize:=numColumnsToCopy).Copy _
                        dest.Offset(RowOffset:=destRowOffset)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next dictKey

Dim msg As String

    For Each dictKey In headersDict
        header = dictKey
        If headersDict.Item(header) = False Then
            msg = msg & vbNewLine & header
        End If
    Next dictKey

ExitSub:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If msg <> "" Then
        MsgBox "The following headers were not copied:" & vbNewLine & msg
    End If
Exit Sub

ErrorMessage:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred: " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitSub

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Tagging your question appropriately will usually assist in getting your answer. This is not `vbscript` as you've tagged, since VBS is not a type-safe language, nor does it have `Sheets()` functions, `On Error Goto ...` statements, Excel constants (`xlUp`), etc. While I fixed it, I point this out now so you don't run into issues with other questions. Also, I'd recommend that you [edit] your question that better explains what you're trying to accomplish, because coding and jigsaw puzzles are not the same thing. A couple lines of code doesn't have its own mandatory spot in the runtime sequence.

Comment: What "errors" are you having? The code could be placed anywhere in your functions. Where do you want the copy/paste to happen?

Comment: Why do you want doing that? Did your boss tell you that it would be good to be done? If not, can you explain why? Otherwise, it is difficult to deduce what you want accomplishing, if you do not tell it...

Comment: I don't think the workbook in the code has a `Sheets1` or `Sheets2` worksheet - they are all named in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of yours just replace `Report.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=numRowsToCopy, ColumnSize:=numColumnsToCopy).Copy _ dest.Offset(RowOffset:=destRowOffset)`

with
`Report.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=numRowsToCopy,ColumnSize:=numColumnsToCopy).Copy`
`dest.Offset(RowOffset:=destRowOffset).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Comment: It gives me a "Compile Error: Expected: end of statement"  I am a VBA newbie so I don't know how to fix this error.